# SymmetricDS Error 404 during registration

Tags: tomcat, symmetricds

I am trying to synchronize nodes with SymmetricDS, but I have some problems. I deploy war on TomCat 7. It starts up, creates tables and everything seems okay, but another nodes cannot register and when I visit registration URL, I get 404 response.

Other nodes which are trying to connect gets:

```
 Could not register.  Sleeping for 4000 ms before attempting again.
 This node is unregistered.  It will attempt to register using the registration.url
    Failed while reading batch because: http://localhost:8181/sync/registration...
    caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

server has this settings:

```
registration.url=http://localhost:8181/sync
sync.url=http://localhost:8181/sync
auto.registration=true
```

clients:

```
registration.url=http://localhost:8181/sync
auto.registration=true
```

Tomcat manager shows server as running. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were problem with URL... correct is:

```
http://localhost:8181/warName/sync
```

Comment: What is with Spring boot? what is the warName there?